# how to remove unwanted space between the div and html?

Tags: html, css

When i make an angular project, everything seemed to be fine when i gave the ng serve command but after a while i noticed that there is a weird space between the div and the html and no matter what i do this space does not seem to go. there is literally just a div in this angular project.
its as if the div has a border which i don't have the control of. even after opening the console and inspecting the element i found that there is no padding or margin, its just pure div that has some space between the screen and itself but why and how do i remove it because its not there normally.

I have tried css properties like o padding or margin but to no avail but the thing is this space shouldn't come here in the first place.

app.component.css

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center; height: 50px; background-color: black;">
</div>
```

thats all the HTML inside it.

[picture of the html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ANi8_QfQJrPdL2Qmp_uqEwjhij1J4Sef/view?usp=sharing)

[The inspect element view of div](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18QLFgb6m-02St5c7Z9fpKo95KHRhOTeE/view?usp=sharing)

[The inspect element view of HTML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12r91mKkBX6-b9zORKjOGyGaWhe0Ypsag/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you paste HTML code here please

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or something?  I don't understand what you mean about space between your div and html.  html inside the div?  If you're talking outside, the element containing your div might have padding...

Comment: The answer posted by @indefinite has a snippet without margin, that is whats happening now ideally providing margin in the css should work but it does not in the case of angular here.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space by using `margin` to `*` in your css

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center; height: 50px; background-color: black;">
</div>
```

sample code without `margin`

```css
html{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center; height: 50px; background-color: black;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but it doesn't work. i have tried it, if i open the inspect element it just purely says there is no padding or margin.
The space is just there for some reason, my inspect element says html dimensions 824x116
div dimensions 808x100.
whats surprising is the code snippet run option provided by stackoverflow gives the same result with your code, there is still the space between the div and the html.

Comment: @vikky Hello and Welcome to SO. maybe you can edit your post and include `html` and `css` code for us to better understand what is the problem. and perhaps a screenshot of the result. Thank you.

Comment: Sir the html code was there but now i have included the css along with the comments. also angular doesn't ask for body or head or html tags.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what your inspect element looks like?  What 'html' element shows 824x116 dimensions?

Comment: I have added the pictures of my inspect element views in the question now, earlier it was not there as stackoverflow didn't allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be trying to style the host element of your component?  Try this:

```
:host {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Link to docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

The styles in your component's css apply to html *inside* your component, but not the element representing your component itself.  If you're talking about the page as a whole, you'll need some global css in your `styles.css` file or whatever to remove margin and padding from the body:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

If your component is contained in some other html or component, that may have some padding or margins you would need to modify as well.

Comment: It did not work, thank you sir. i really appreciate the kindness.
normal html and css works great but as soon as i switch to angular it just ruins it.

Comment: sir there is no other component and also it did not work again, its in the app component which is the outermost and single component in this project. i have worked on angular before but i did not face this issue, i started this new project and this is the first issue i saw.